# using round corners with jquery in ie

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

i am trying to code a cross browser rollover effect in my meny using rounded corners but is not working in ie. I was trying to use PIE even some pllugins but they didnt work.

this is my code:

```
$("document").ready(function() {

var ancho = $('nav li.nav_active').width()+24;

    $('nav li.nav_active').css({
            'background-color' : '#282828',
            "height" : ancho+"px",
            'margin-top' : "-"+(ancho-48)/2+"px",
            '-moz-border-radius' : ancho/2+"px",
            '-webkit-border-radius' : ancho/2+"px", 
            '-khtml-border-radius' : ancho/2+"px",
            'border-radius' : ancho/2+"px", 
            'behavior' : 'url(../PIE.htc)',
            '-webkit-box-shadow' : '0 8px 6px -6px black',
            '-moz-box-shadow' : '0 8px 6px -6px black',
            'box-shadow' : '0 8px 6px -6px black',
            'border' : 'none'
            });
            $('nav li.nav_active a').css({
            "line-height" : ancho+"px",
            "color" : "white",
            "font-family" : "'E-BoldCondensed'",
            });






$(function() {
    $('nav li:not(.nav_active)').mouseover(
        function () {
            var ancho = $(this).width()+32;
            $(this).css({
            "height" : ancho+"px",
            'margin-top' : "-"+(ancho-48)/2+"px",
            '-moz-border-radius' : ancho/2+"px",
            '-webkit-border-radius' : ancho/2+"px", 
            '-khtml-border-radius' : ancho/2+"px",
            'border-radius' : ancho/2+"px", 
            'behavior' : 'url(../PIE.htc)',
            '-webkit-box-shadow' : '0 8px 6px -6px black',
            '-moz-box-shadow' : '0 8px 6px -6px black',
            'box-shadow' : '0 8px 6px -6px black',
            });
            $(this,'a').css({
            "line-height" : ancho+"px",
            });
        });
});

$(function() {
    $('nav li:not(.nav_active)').mouseleave(
        function () {

            $(this).css({
            "height" : "",
            'margin-top' : "",
            '-moz-border-radius' : "",
            '-webkit-border-radius' : "", 
            '-khtml-border-radius' : "",
            'border-radius' : "",
            '-webkit-box-shadow' : '',
            '-moz-box-shadow' : '',
            'box-shadow' : '',

            });
            $(this,'a').css({
            "line-height" : '',
            });
        });
}); 

$(function() {
    $('nav li').mousedown(
        function () {
            var ancho = $(this).width()+32;
            $(this).css({
            "height" : ancho+"px",
            'margin-top' : "-"+(ancho-48)/2+"px",
            '-moz-border-radius' : ancho/2+"px",
            '-webkit-border-radius' : ancho/2+"px", 
            '-khtml-border-radius' : ancho/2+"px",
            'border-radius' : ancho/2+"px", 
            'behavior' : 'url(../PIE.htc)',
            '-webkit-box-shadow' : '',
            '-moz-box-shadow' : '',
            'box-shadow' : '',
            });
            $(this,'a').css({
            "line-height" : ancho+"px",
            });
        });
});

});
```

this in the link of my website:   www.miramarlab.com

Comment: Why don't you just put all that in a class and use `addClass()` instead of `css()` ??

Comment: Which version of IE? Have you tried setting up the PIE corners statically, not with JS? I'm betting that PIE does not work with dynamically-added CSS.

Comment: I am using css() because I need to get the width value of the li in order to calculate the radius of the corner to make a perfect circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without `jquery` (and even without images) using `CSS` only and it will be better. Please read this article: http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers.
Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you should call the htc file relative to the html page, not the css. maybe that is the culprit, and the htc file has a specific mime type that should be added in a .htaccess file.

save the htc file in the root directory and load it with an absolute path:

```
behavior: url (http://www.miramarlab.com/PIE.htc);
```